# Why ordinalIndexOf() not working in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Groovy code :

```
println 'hello'.indexOf ('l',1)
println 'hello'.ordinalIndexOf('l',1)
```

Output :

```
2
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.ordinalIndexOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [l, 1]
```

What i am missing here ? and How to use `ordinalIndexOf()` ?

Comment: This method does not exist in `String` nor in `GString` class. Where did you take it from?

Comment: Apache Commons has one - [`StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `String` has no method `ordinalIndexOf` and Groovy doesn't add one either which is what the error message tells you.

Where this method exists is in the class `StringUtils` in `commons-lang` and `commons-lang3`. You can either use that method or add the method to the `String` class, for example by using `StringUtils` as category class like

```
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7')
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

println 'hello'.indexOf('l',1)
println StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf('hello','l',1)
use (StringUtils) {
    println 'hello'.ordinalIndexOf('l',1)
}
```

which prints `2` three times.

Answer (score 1):

One can add a method to `String`'s [MetaClass](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaClass.html):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

String.metaClass.ordinalIndexOf { String searchStr, int ordinal ->
    StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(delegate, searchStr, ordinal)
}

println 'hello'.ordinalIndexOf('l',1)
```